# Plotting the intersection of a ball and a plane

Tags: plotting, regions

I want to draw a semi-transparent ball and highlight its intersection with a plane.

```
ℛ = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 , {x, y, z}];

r3d = 
  RegionPlot3D[ℛ, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.6, 1.6}}, 
    PlotPoints -> 30]

inter = 
  Region[RegionIntersection[ℛ, InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]]]
```

Now why won't this work?

```
RegionPlot3D[inter, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.6, 1.6}},  
  PlotPoints -> 30]
```

I have a implicit region and a plane, I form the intersection, but I'm unable to plot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand `inter` is already a `Region` and need not be wrapped by `RegionPlot3D`. `RegionPlot3D` wants to have a boolean expression as first argument; since an `ImplicitRegion` essentially consists of such a boolean expression, `RegionPlot3D` was also overloaded for `ImplicitRegion`s.

On the other hand, `ℛ` is a `ImplicitRegion`; these are not plotted automatically. But you can turn it into a `Region` with `Region[ℛ]` to obtain a preview or apply `DiscretizeRegion` or `DiscretizeBoundaryRegion` to compute polyhedral approximations.

As side remark: `RegionPlot3D` was introduced in version 6.0 while `Region` was introduced in version 11.1. So `RegionPlot3D` follows an older mechanic; it was not meant as displaying/plotting function for `Region`s, even if the name might suggest that.

Answer (score 1):

The `why` was answered long ago. This covers the mechanical details for visualizing the regions.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ℛ = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
ℛshell = 
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}];

plane = InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}];
inter = RegionIntersection[ℛ, plane];
outer = RegionIntersection[
   ℛshell, plane
   ];

To visualize:

Show[
 Region[Style[ℛ, Opacity[0.4, White]]
  , SphericalRegion -> True]
 , Region[Style[inter, Opacity[0.3, Green]]]
 , Region[Style[outer, {Thick, Red}]]
 , Region[Style[plane, Opacity[0.4, Orange]]]
 , Graphics3D[{Point@RandomPoint[DiscretizeRegion@ℛshell, 100]}]
 ]
```

[image]

---

**Addendum**

To view the circle inside the sphere with a dashed or hatched pattern, use the following variation:

```
Show[
 Region[Style[ℛ, Opacity[0.4, White]]
  , SphericalRegion -> True]
 , Region[Style[outer, {Thick, Red}]]
 , Region[Style[plane, Opacity[0.4, Orange]]]
 , Graphics3D[{Point@RandomPoint[DiscretizeRegion@ℛshell, 100]}]
 , RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@inter
  , Mesh -> 10
  , MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}
  , MeshShading -> {{Black, Yellow}, {Pink, Red}}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Can I view dashed of the circle inside of sphere?

Comment: I have updated the answer; please take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much.